# ifft(fft(function)) doesn't give the original function

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm a bit puzzled by the following argument.

I'm trying to simulate the Talbot effect using a gaussian beam impinging upon a phase grating and for some reason I'm unable to produce a Talbot carpet using a pi phase. The problem seems to lie withing the fft of the grating defined as follows:

```
def binary_grating(x,Amin,Amax,period,phase):

a = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]<-period/4 or x[i]>period/4:
        c=0
        b = Amin*np.exp(1j*phase*c)
    else:
        c=1
        b = Amax*np.exp(1j*phase*c)
            
    a.append(b)
            
return np.array(a)
```

which gives the following amplitude and phases

[amplitude and phase of the grating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfLk6.jpg)

I'm using the fft to obtain the fourier coefficients of the grating which will be used in the interaction and Fresnel propagation of the gaussian beam. When I check for the coefficients and try to obtain the starting grating with the inverse fft

```
rec = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(grating))
```

I get the following

[amplitude and phase of the grating after ifft(fft(grating))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXupg.jpg)

which is a resonable reason behind the impossibility of getting a pi Talbot carpet simulation.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ifft( fft(x) ) will return x in complex; what's your intent here?

Comment: @P2000 I think they meant *inverse FFT*, not `FFT * i` there...?

Comment: @P2000 x is indeed complex since must include an amplitude and a phase

Comment: perhaps you could include a reference to the equation with the fft and include a screenshot of it in your post.

Comment: @FZs I'm not following.... the IFFT of FFT(x) will return x, (in numpy the result will be complex with practically zero imag, even if x was real - if that subtlety even matters to the OP)

Comment: There are rounding errors when computing the FFT. Where your amplitude is 0, the phase is ill-defined. A small amount of error (=noise) will make the phase jump all over the place. You should never attempt to compute the phase of a complex number that is approximately 0.

Comment: @P2000 I'm using C = np.fft.fft(grating) to obtain the fourier coefficients. Similar output happens using scipy.fft.fft

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes i figured that. Problem is, how do I solve it?

Comment: With something like "if magnitude < 1e-12, phase = 0". Pick whatever magnitude threshold makes sense for  your data. It should be related to the maximum magnitude in the signal and the floating-point precision.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you for your suggestion. I applied it and it worked. Also I had to consider only the real part of the first fourier coefficient.